# How to show push notifications in foreground with react-native-firebase v6?

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I've had several issues migrating from react native firebase v5 to v6. It seems that there's no notifications() method in v6. How to properly display the notifications in foreground with react native firebase v6?

my code with v5 works:

```
    async listenToPushNots(){
            firebase.notifications().onNotificationDisplayed(notification => {
                  console.log("XXXXX onNotificationDisplayed", notification);
                });
            
                firebase.notifications().onNotification(notification => {
                 //remote notification received
                  console.log("XXXXX LISTENER onNotification", notification);
            
                  // notification.android.setChannelId(notification._notificationId);
                  // firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification);
            
                  const localNotification = new firebase.notifications.Notification({
                    sound: "default",
                    show_in_foreground: true,
                    show_in_background: true
                  })
                    .setNotificationId(notification._notificationId)
                    .setTitle(notification._data.title)
                    .setSubtitle(notification._data.body)
                    .setBody(notification._data.body)
                    .setData(notification._data)
                    .android.setChannelId("my-app-channel")
                    .android.setSmallIcon("ic_stat_ic_notif") // create this icon in Android Studio
                    .android.setLargeIcon("ic_launcher_round")
                    .android.setColor("#000000") // you can set a color here
                    .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High);
            
                  firebase
                    .notifications()
                    .displayNotification(localNotification)
                    .catch(err => console.error(err));
            }
        
        async componentDidMount(){
         listenToPushNots();
        }
```

In v6 how would firebase.notifications() be replaced? There is no reference in their official docs on how to properly migrate (https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/notifications). The messaging() method does not include notifications unlike v5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from their documentation (https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage), you can't use react-native-firebase v6 for foreground notification:

[image]

The best way to add foreground notification, is to add https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

Comment:   just realised! I can't believe that their v6 is inferior than their v5! Thx, I might consider switching back to v5 after this than having to create the whole thing all over again with a new module...

Comment: I strongly suggest you to go with the V6, the v5 is too old and deprecated. It's not so hard to integrate the new module, but I went through your same problem :( however if my answer resolved your question please mark it. Regards

Comment: But I mean I have everything ready with v5 including setup and configs on manifest xml and ios appdelegates etc and actually works. I can't believe I have to go through this nightmare again. I suppose yeah your answer covered it but i wish it didn't..

Comment: you can find here the relative issue: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2566

Comment: Thx Francesco! Unbelievable what they've done! They separated the module and charge $240 for it lol (for doing exactly the same thing). I guess I have no other option than to use v6 and redo the whole thing with react-native push notification module

Comment: Exactly. I went with v6 + react-native-push-notification. To give you a big tips, you need to still use the token generated from react-native-firebase messaging module. react-native-push-notification generate an APN token but you need a FCM token. However in some apps, I managed all in a different way. You can still use only react-native-firebase and replace the foreground notification with simply alert. Good luck

Comment: Thx once again Francesco!

Comment: sorry for coming back to it Francesco, I've done it but the background message is not displayed on android. it works all fine on iOS. the notification is received but not displayed. I need to swipe to see notifications to see it. Have you encountered this with v6? I haven't had that issue with v5..

Comment: Did you set the importance_high on notification options? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#IMPORTANCE_HIGH

Comment: How? in v5 i was doing this on /app component only and worked, on v6 notifications module is missing: 
const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(
  "app-channel",
  "myapp Channel",
  firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max
).setDescription("myapp Channel");

firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);

Comment: can't remember the specific implementation. You could find it easily on react-native-firebase issues

Comment: Managed to do it Francesco! it seems that with v6 you can add a firebase.json file and clarify the channel name, then set high priority on index.js with push not module PushNotification.createChannel({importance: "high",  channelId: "myapp-channel" }). only issue now is that on foreground the icon of the app is not appearing... seems to be working on background or if app is closed. if you know, pls share :)

Comment: using react-push-notifications we can see the notification in foreground but then dere doesnt seem to b a way by which we can handle a click event in there.